# VSTS Release Management for Nuget Package with Hosted Linux Preview using dotnet

Tags: linux, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

Is it possible to setup a release management task that works for the Hosted Linux Preview Agent that pushes a nuget package using dotnet push?

I've got a Build process that creates the nuget package and publishes it as an artifact.  So far I've got this, which works when I use the Hosted VS2017 Agent.

[image: Release Task]

The error i'm getting is:

```
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3084270Z ##[section]Starting: dotnet push
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3413530Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3426100Z Task         : .NET Core
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3439540Z Description  : Build, test, package, or publish a dotnet application, or run a custom dotnet command. For package commands, supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3451740Z Version      : 2.1.8
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3464910Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3477740Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
2017-11-16T09:08:37.3491430Z ==============================================================================
2017-11-16T09:08:40.3181020Z ##[error]No packages matched the search pattern.
2017-11-16T09:08:40.3305430Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet push
```

I'm wondering if there is a difference between the agents on how they pattern match file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that backslashes and forward slashes are pretty important.

I changed the *Path to NuGet package(s) to publish* to use forward slashes `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg`

And what do you know, it works :D